# How to reconfigure Kconfig settings?

Tags: linux, build, kernel

I'm trying to build a custom linux kernel. The first time I was asked questions about my configuration, these questions had a (NEW) tag associated with them.

But now I want to run compile the kernel again and be asked the same questions again. How do I go about "clearing" the configuration settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
# make clean
```

Or Just delete follwoing file in kernel source directory

```
.config
```

Comment: Yep. I was in a separate branch then I was supposed to be in which is why I did not notice the changes. Also I found out that a "make mrproper" is more thorough than a "make clean" for linux compilation.